# Perl one-liner to match all occurrences of regex

Tags: regex, perl

For multiple lines of text similar to this:

```
"views_panes","gw_hero_small_site_placement-panel_pane_1",1,"a:0:{}","a:10:{s:14:\"override_title\";i:1;s:19:\"override_title_text\";s:0:\"\";s:9:\"view_mode\";s:11:\"all_purpose\";s:11:\"image_style\";s:7:\"default\";s:13:\"style_options\";a:2:{s:10:\"show_image\";i:0;s:9:\"show_date\";i:0;}s:18:\"gw_display_options\";s:22:\"gw_all_purpose_sidebar\";s:13:\"show_readmore\";a:1:{s:18:\"show_readmore_link\";i:0;}s:14:\"readmore_title\";s:9:\"Read more\";s:13:\"readmore_link\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"exposed\";a:1:{s:23:\"field_hero_sub_type_tid\";s:3:\"547\";}}","a:0:{}","a:1:{s:8:\"settings\";N;}","a:0:{}","a:0:{}",0,"s:0:\"\";"
```

I am looking to match all instances of `(s:)(\d{1,}:)\"(string)\";` to get something like this:

```
s:14:override_title
s:18:show_readmore_link
s:3:547
```

This line with or without `/g` prints only the first instances:

```
perl -nle 'print  "$1 $2 $3"  if /(s:)(\d{1,}:)\\"(.*?)\\";/g' tmp.txt

s:14:override_title
```

I suppose I can try to put this in a perl script putting all matches into an array, but am hoping to do this using a one-liner (-: What am I missing?

Mac OS X 10.7.5, perl 5.12.3.

Comment: Isn't that string JSON?

Comment: @M42: I'm not sure. Would that be helpful if it were ... ?

Comment: @M42: http://jsonlint.com/ doesn't think it is, even if wrapped in `[ ]` or `{ }`

Comment: @NeilSlater: You're rigth, my bad.

Comment: @M42 Parts of it can be deserialized using `PHP::Serialization`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's seem you have only line, so have a try with:

```
perl -nle 'print  "$1 $2 $3"  while(/.*?(s:)(\d{1,}:)\\"(.*?)\\";/g)' tmp.txt
```

Comment: Works charmingly, thank you! So the `if` doesn't work because once it hits the first match, all conditions are satisfied and it stops? Any way I could've debugged that?