# Unix - filename and string result on same line

Tags: perl, unix, grep

I need to search a directory that has hundreds or thousands of files, each containing XML with one or more instances of a specific string (begin/end tag with data). 
I can get all the instances of the string by doing

```
grep -ho '<mytagname>..............<\/mytagname>' /home/xyzzy/mydata/*.XML > /home/mydata/tagvalues.txt
```

then a few sed commands to strip off the tags, so I wind up with a file just containing a list of values:

```
  value001
  value002
  value003
```

(etc)

Ideally though, I'd like to have each line of the file to also include the filename so I can import into a database for analysis.

So my result would be something like this

```
fileAAA value001
fileAAA value002
fileAAA value003
fileBBB value004
```

Exact formatting of the above is flexible - could have spaces or other separator, it could even still include the begin/end tags.

The closest I've been able to get is with grep -o

```
fileAAA:value001
value002
value003
fileBBB:value004
```

A perl one-liner would seem ideal but I'm new enough to that, that I have no clue how to begin.

Answer (score 4):

Could be done using a one-liner like so:

```
perl -lne 'print "$ARGV $1" if /<mytagname>(.*?)<\/mytagname>/' *.xml
```

However, I'd strongly recommend that you use an actual XML parser like [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

for my $file (</home/xyzzy/mydata/*.XML>) {
    my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);
    for my $node ($doc->findnodes("//mytagname")) {
        print "$file " . $node->textContent() . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about awk?

```
awk -F'</?mytagname>' '$2 {print FILENAME,$2}' /home/xyzzy/mydata/*.XML
```

Explanation:

- `-F regex` - set field delimiter must be a separate argument thus enclosed in its own quotes
- `$2` - if second field has a value
- `{print FILENAME,$2}` - print filename SPACE the value of second field

Comment: Thanks - both of those (the perl and the awk) work to some extent: they appear to only take the first occurrence of the string in the file. When I use my original grep, I'm getting many thousands of hits (even after I sort and take unique values). When I use either of the commands as is, I get about 7500 hits, which is the number of files in the directory.

Comment: Aha - did a little digging and found the answer in another posting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031552/perl-one-liner-to-match-all-occurrences-of-regex) - so I changed the perl command to while( /<mytagname>(.*?)<\/mytagname>/g)' instead of the if - and that's giving me a more believable number.